# "Path" to proxy box on applescript?

Tags: macos, proxy, applescript

I am trying to use apple script to open 2 proxies in system preferences (which I have to use to access this site) but i can't get the script to click the check boxes. Code follows:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.network"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Network"
    click button "Advanced…"
    delay 2
    tell TabGroup of sheet 1
        tell radio button "proxies"
            click
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I want the code to click the http and https proxy boxes which are in the proxies tab which are  part of the advanced slide down tab but I don't know what the "path" is. Could anybody help me with this? Thanks;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses Web Proxy:

```
 tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.network"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Network"
    click button "Advanced…"
    delay 2
    click radio button "Proxies" of tab group 1 of sheet 1
    delay 2

    repeat until focused of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1
        keystroke tab
    end repeat

    -- Make sure you start from the top of the list
    repeat 20 times
        key code 126 -- up arrow Key
        delay 0.2
    end repeat

    set counter to 0
    repeat until (value of static text of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1 as text) contains "Web Proxy Server"
        set counter to counter + 1
        key code 125
        if counter ≥ 100 then
            display dialog "You have not entered a valid protocol name" buttons {"OK"}
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    delay 1
    click checkbox 1 of row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, how did you get the path?

Comment: Thank you but I still have a problem.....when i change "SOCKS Proxy" to "Web Proxy (HTTP)" and run it, the whole computer freezes. Could You Please tell me why and a alternative?

Comment: You need to use the value to the right of "Select a protocol to configure:", not what appears in the list.

Comment: `set selected of row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1 to true`

Answer (score 0):

To decide which box you wanna check, you only have to change the row number. Right now it's set to toggle SOCKS proxy.

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Preferences" to set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.network"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
    click button "Advanced…"
    click radio button "Proxies" of tab group 1 of sheet 1
    set box to checkbox 1 of row 6 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1
    set selected of row 6 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of sheet 1 to true
    click box
    set val to the value of box as boolean
    click button "OK" of sheet 1
    click button "Apply"
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
if val is true then return "Toggled On"
if val is false then return "Toggled Off"
```